# Shell ps command under Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a question regarding shell scripts. I am trying to be as specific as possible. So, I have to write a monitoring shell script in which I have to write in a file all the users that are running a vi command more, than one minute. I don't really have any idea about the approach, except that I should use the ps command. I have something like this:

ps -ewo "%t %u %c %g" | grep '\< vi >'

with this I get the times and the users that run a vi command. The problem is that I don't really know how to parse the result of this command. Can anyone help, please? All answers are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will use awk:

```
ps eo user,etime,pid,args --no-heading -C vi | awk '{MIN=int(substr($2,0,2)); printf "minutes=%s pid=%d\n", MIN, $3; }'
```

Note, that you dont have to grep for "vi", you can use "ps -C procname".

Comment: `ps e` doesn't output other users' processes. `etime` may have additional fields, `etimes` is safer. Also you don't filter by 1 min time.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i'd do:

```
ps fo "etime,user" --no-heading --sort 'uid,-etime' $(pgrep '\<vi\>') |
    perl -ne '($min,$sec,$user) = (m/^\s+(\d\d):(\d\d)\s+(\w+)$/mo); 
               print "$user\t$min:$sec\n" unless ((0+$min)*60+$sec)<60'
```

Tack on `| cut -f1 | uniq` or `| cut -f1 | uniq -c` to get some nicer stats

Note that the way this is formulated it is easy to switch the test to 59 seconds or 3min11s if you so wish by changing `<60` to e.g. `<191` (for 3m11s)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 

while true
    process="ps eo user,etime,args"
    f = IO.popen(process) #call the ps command
    f.readlines.each do|ps|
        user, elapsed, command = ps.split
        if command["vi"] && elapsed > "01:00"
            puts "User #{user} running vi for more than 1 minute: #{elapsed}"
        end
    end
    f.close
    sleep 10 # sleep 10 seconds before monitoring again
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
# -e           :: all processes (inluding other users')
# -o           :: define output format
# user         :: user name
# etimes       :: time in seconds after the process was started
# pid          :: process id
# comm         :: name of the executable
# --no-headers :: do not print column names
ps -eo user,etimes,pid,comm --no-headers |
awk '
# (...)       :: select only rows that meet the condition in ()
# $4 ~ //     :: 4th field (comm) should match the pattern in //
# (^|\/)vim?$ :: beginning of the line or "/", then "vi",
#                nothing or "m" (to capture vim), end of the line
# $2 > 60     :: 2nd field (etimes) >= 60 seconds
($4 ~ /(^|\/)vim?$/ && $2 >= 60){
# convert 2nd field (etimes) into minutes
  t = int($2 / 60);
# check if the time is more than 1 minute
  s = (t > 1) ? "s" : "";
# output
  printf "user %s : [%s] (pid=%d) started %d minute%s ago\n", $1, $4, $3, t, s;
}'
```